# How can I remove this brass bathtub spout adapter?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub

I am trying to replace the spout in our bathtub. The original spout itself came off easy enough, but then things got hard. There was an extension tube that took way too much effort to unscrew and once I got that off, I discovered what I'm guessing is an adapter (pictured), and I cannot get that to loosen up at all. I've drenched it in WD-40 and am at a loss.

[image: adapter?]

Answer (score 2):

It's probably sweated on. Look for solder at the rear seam.

To remove it, pull the O-ring off to prevent its destruction, then heat the back end of the brass fitting evenly around its circumference with your plumbing torch. Periodically check for movement with a plier.

Protect the tub with some towels.

Comment: Thanks. Any way to do it without a torch?

Comment: Sure. A hack saw. Then you have a shorter pipe. You should own a plumbing torch anyway. It's a homeowner essential.

Comment: @Billybrownbear   A torch is the easy way.  Just make that pipe is drained of water first.  Turn off the shut off valve and open the tub valve.  Can also use/give the torch to your favourite chef after.